# How to Implement Look inside the Book Feature for Magento 1.9.3.9?

Tags: magento-1.9, database, extensions, pdf, magento1.9.3

I want to develop a "**Look Inside the Book**" feature similar to what Amazon has.

Does anyone have a suggestion how I could achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach would be to add the pages that you want to be visible to the product image gallery. You'd have to ensure that the gallery is configured to show full size images in a way that makes the pages legible.